# MEAN Stack : module .exports is not a function

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm getting the error in my schema file. This is my code.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var jobListSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    companyName: String,
    jobtitle: String,
    location: String
});

const JobList = module.exports('JobList',jobListSchema);
```

This is my error:

> TypeError: module.exports is not a function
>       at Object. (D:\product\project-1\models\joblist.js:9:24)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object. (D:\product\project-1\routes\users.js:8:17)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

Comment: guess You want to export model by Schema: `module.exports = mongoose.model('JobList', jobListSchema);`

Answer (score 1):

module.exports is a property, not a function

Try this

```
module.exports = { 'jobList': jobListSchema };
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like You want to export mongoose model not Schema.

It will be like this:

`db/JobList.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const definition = {
    companyName: Schema.Types.String,
    jobtitle: Schema.Types.String,
    location: Schema.Types.String
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('JobList', new Schema(definition));
```

**BONUS**

usage example in `express` app sample:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

// connection and etc... goes here
mongoose.connect(
  'mongo://127.0.0.1:21017/dbname_here', 
  {
    config: {autoIndex: false}
  }
);

// here we define models that we want to require
const JobList = require('./db/JobList');

const express = require('express'); // installation: npm i --save express
const app = express();
const _ = require('lodash'); // installation: npm i --save lodash


app.get('/vacancies', async (req, res) => {
  const query = _.pick(req.query, ['joblist', 'location', 'companyName']);
  const vacancies = await JobList.find(query).limit(20).lean();
  res.status(200).send({vacancies});
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try refactoring it...

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var jobListSchema = new Schema({
    companyName: String,
    jobtitle: String,
    location: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("NAME", jobListSchema);
```

Comment: then I'm getting error as const JobList = module.exports('JobList', jobListSchema);
                                                                             ^